# kafka + what could be the reasons for kafka broker isn't the leader for topic partition

Tags: apache-kafka

we have HDP cluster - 2.6.4 with ambari 2.6.1 version

we have 3 kafka brokers with version 10.1 , and 3 zookeeper servers

we saw in the /var/log/kafka/server.log many errors messages as :

in this example we have 6601 errors lines about:

```
This server is not the leader for that topic-partition
```

example

```
[2019-01-06 14:56:53,312] ERROR [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-1011], Error for partition [topic1-example,34] to broker 1011:org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This server is not the leader for that topic-partition. (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
```

we check the connectivity's between the kafka brokers and connectivity seems to be ok ( we verify the /var/log/messages and dmesg on the Linux kafka machines )

we are also suspect is the connections between the zookeeper client on kafka brokers to the zookeepers servers

but we not know how to check the relationship between client on kafka to zookeeper servers

we also know that kafka send heartbeat to zookeeper servers ( I think the heartbeat value is 2 seconds ) but we not sure if this is the right direction to search what cause the leader to disappears

any ideas what are the reasons that -  kafka broker isn't the leader for topic partition ?

other related links

https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/0.10.2.0/source-code/org/apache/kafka/common/protocol/Errors.java

[kafka : one broker keeping print INFO log : "NOT_LEADER_FOR_PARTITION"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51237508/kafka-one-broker-keeping-print-info-log-not-leader-for-partition)

https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/issues/297

Comment: Please show the description of `topic1-example`

Comment: now leaders are balanced , but before two days it wasn't balanced

Comment: maybe some usful tool that can diagnostic problem on kafka as topic not rebalanced or missing broker id ,etc

Comment: JMX metrics maybe. As explained before, "balanced" and "missing replicas" are different terms in kafka

Comment: can we get more how to monitor with JMX?

Comment: https://medium.com/@mousavi310/monitor-apache-kafka-using-grafana-and-prometheus-873c7a0005e2

Comment: Seems similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47767169/kafka-this-server-is-not-the-leader-for-that-topic-partition